# Eclipse Cpp - What is the difference between C Project, C/C++ Project and C++ Project?

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-cdt, projects-and-solutions

In Eclipse CDT IDE that i downloaded for Linux (because unfortunately Code::Blocks on Linux/Unix doesn't work so well for me) i am given these three options for creating a project. I can understand the difference between a C and a C++ Project of course. But what exactly is the C/C++ Project? Which one should i choose for C++ development? I can't find clear information on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=68835&goto=215834&#msg_215834

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C/C++ Project is the new wizard to create projects. If you select it, on the next page you will get the choice of C or C++ project:

[image]

The new wizard has been created to unify all the wizards and make adding new ones nicer and easier. For example, if you have Arduino tools installed then you can create an Ardunio sketch that way.

If you just want a C or a C++ Project, choosing the C/C++ New Project wizard just means one extra click.

Comment: So C and C++ projects use CDT as well huh? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, CDT is short for C Developer Tools and provides all the tooling for C and C++ projects. There is another layer that people like the Arduino project and gnu mcu eclipse https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/ provides on top of that to essentially provide defaults/ custom project types/ etc

Comment: I find it strange that the initial options in the new wizard are both "managed build" projects, but on the next page you can make it a makefile project...